# Load balancing (Distribution) with PHP and many servers

Tags: php, redirect, server, load-balancing

[image: Servers]

I am developing an app which has many users and (hopefully) will have many more in the future and therefore I want to get rid of my current one-server-makes-it-all solution to a many server structure. My app has customers in different countries and I want to handle each country with an own server. You can see this in the picture above. The app only knows the URL of the distribution server and I want to achieve, that the distribution server redirects to the right server. 
How can I technically do this? I am using PHP / MySQL and my app is talking to my server with simple HTTP requests (GET and maybe later also POST) like

```
http://distributionServer.com/script.php?appCountry=us&work=getListOfItems
```

Server Sends back JSON data.

I have some technical questions:

1. how to make the redirect in PHP with all the parameters? The Servers that will finally handle the user need these params. Can I just make a simple redirect with "header()" ?
2. When I make redirect with header() does the communication still runs then over the distribution server? Because I don't want that all the "return" traffic is going over the distribution server, this server only needs to say "ok USA-App you talk to server USA". When server USA sends back data it should not go the way: ServerUSA -> Distribution Server -> App. Because these Server do not share a LAN, just somewhere in the net.

I know I could just hardcode the server URLs in the app so that US user always connect directly to USA Server but I need some flexibility to add new servers / change servers / change URLs / add new countries.. and I don't want to always update the app when something changed on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

This is simplest way you can do this : https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/simple-load-balancing-with-apache/